# Simple way to re-run try block if a specific exception occurs?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django and trying to figure out how to rerun a try block if a specific exception is thrown.  I have

```
for article in all_articles:
    try:
        self.save_article_stats(article)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
        if err.code == 503:
            print("Got 503 error when looking for stats on " + url)
        else:
            raise
```

What I would like is if a 503 errors occurs, for the section in the "try" to be re-run, a maximum of three times.  Is there a simple way to do this in Python?

Comment: What should happen if the third attempt fails? Move on to the next article, or re-raise the `HTTPError`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn this in a `for` loop, and `break` in case the `try` block was successful:

```
for article in all_articles:
    for __ in range(3):
        try:
            self.save_article_stats(article)
            break
        except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
            if err.code == 503:
                print("Got 503 error when looking for stats on " + url)
            else:
                raise
```

In case the error code is *not* 503, then the error will reraise, and the control flow will exit the `for` loops.